# CMake Regex Glomming Matches Together

Tags: regex, cmake

The CMake documentation for `string` command says:

> REGEX MATCH will match the regular expression once and store the match
>   in the output variable.

However, when I search for a pattern as follows:

```
STRING(REGEX MATCH "#import <(.+)>" input_directive "${shader_code}")
```

where "${shader_code}" is:

```
#import <../ColorCorrection.glsl>
#import <../YCbCrtoRGB.glsl>

uniform sampler2DRect srcFrame;
uniform vec2 sourceDimensions;
```

I get the result as:

```
#import <../ColorCorrection.glsl>
#import <../YCbCrtoRGB.glsl>
```

This shouldn't be the case. I ought to get just the first line in the result. It looks like it searches for this pattern several times and gloms it together.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way around it? Basically, I want only the first of all the #import statements from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour.  CMake's regex parsing can be a bit tricky, and the documentation is light on examples.

In your regex, you have `<(.+)>`.  This means search for `<`, followed by *any* character one or more times, followed by `>`.  The problem is that the `.*` allows for the first `>` to be consumed, and also all the following characters up until the very last `>` in the string.

To get your desired behaviour, I think specifying any character except `>` will do the trick:

```
STRING(REGEX MATCH "#import <[^>]+>" input_directive "${shader_code}")
```

Comment: That did it! You're a lifesaver. I had just about given up on CMake and was planning to rewrite the entire thing in C++ using boost.regex